# SSMS works, Linked Server does not

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

Linked Server SS 2012(SP4) to SS 2016(SP1) just stopped working. It times out with the error "Server is not found or not accessible". However I can connect and query the target server successfully with SSMS. How can SSMS work yet Linked Server cannot even "see" the target server?

Comment: How is the linked server mapping the credentials? 
Are they still present and working correctly on server 1.
If the user on server 1 maps to a different user on server 2 can you log into server 2 using those same credentials?

Comment: KevH, I am using the same credentials in Object Explorer which is working. The logins work if I connect via a query window, but the Linked Server cannot even "see" the target server.

Comment: Any recent changes to firewall settings?  Any DNS entry changes?  Have you performed an `ipconfig /flushdns` command from the server having issues connecting to the linked server?

Comment: John, Thank you for your comment. While crafting a response I realized that SSMS was connecting from my local machine (successful) while the linked server was connecting from Server A (un-successful). Now I understand the issue and know where to look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an connection issue between Server A and B, NOT local machine and Server B.